# Does the Ext JS 6 classic toolkit support media queries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, sencha-cmd

I Am using the classic toolkit in my application. Does Ext Js  support media queries in its theme file?

Comment: What do you mean by "theme file"?

Comment: I use media queries with no issues in my custom scss files